# ListView acting like a vertical Gallery

Tags: android, android-listview, gallery

as I know, there is no simple way to make Android Gallery vertical. But Gallery have one thing I need - positioning items on a center of View. How can I do this in ListView?

Adapted listView must act like a slot machine - selected item always go to the center of view. It`s kind of "discrete scrolling"

Comment: please make clear what do you want, do you want components to be centered horizontally, and filling device width

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Gravity to position a view within its parent. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```